# How can I set the width of ul list as per the width of dropdown button in react js bootstrap?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am using react bootstrap in my component. When I used dropdown menu it did not take the full width of its container. After a lot of searches, I solved the issue by adding the justified property to the button group, but it increases the size of the drop button only. How can I increases the size of  list also and is there any way to add images within the dropdown menu options?

**this is my code**

```
<ReactBootstrap.Col sm={6} smOffset={3}>
    <ReactBootstrap.ButtonGroup justified>
        <ReactBootstrap.DropdownButton
        title={this.state.dropDownTitle}
        id="bt1"
        onSelect={this.dropDownSelected}
        >
          <ReactBootstrap.MenuItem  eventKey="Online" >Online</ReactBootstrap.MenuItem> 
          <ReactBootstrap.MenuItem  eventKey="Away" >Away</ReactBootstrap.MenuItem> 
          <ReactBootstrap.MenuItem  eventKey="Available" >Available</ReactBootstrap.MenuItem>   
        </ReactBootstrap.DropdownButton>
    </ReactBootstrap.ButtonGroup>   

</ReactBootstrap.Col>
```

[in this image you can see that the ul list is not as per the width of dropdown button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4RpR.png)

Comment: Did you tried to find where in css the width?

Comment: no.Actualy i want a responsive ul list as per my drop down button.